# Android - Does GC collect my outer class if the inner class is a service?

Tags: java, android, service, garbage-collection

I'm currently developing an app for android that has a "Service helper" class so I can target multiple API-s without having to write the "API chooser" code every time I use a Service.

The structure is

- Outer class is not a Service (`extends Object`)
- Inner class #1 is derived from `JobService`, and targets API 21+
- Inner class #2 is derived from `IntentService` and targets lower API levels

The outer class is responsible for holding data required by the services and scheduling the services. The question is: if the activity that created an instance of the outer class gets destroyed by the time the service starts, will GC collect the outer class? (I don't hold a reference to it in any of the inner classes apart from `OuterClass.this`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything has a reference to the outer class, then it cannot be garbage collected.

An inner class holds a reference to the outer class, so if anything has a reference to an inner class, then they indirectly hold a reference to the outer class, and it cannot be garbage collected.